# Is there a way to start playing music on Spotify with an intent?

Tags: java, android, spotify

I am working on an application for Android that should start playing a specific playlist on Spotify. Trying to use intents I was only able to open the playlist on the Spotify app, not to play it. Is there a way to start playing the music with an intent or have I to use the Spotify SDK?

Answer (score 3):

yes, use the following intent:

```
Intent spotifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXaTIN6XNquoW:play"));
startActivity(spotifyIntent);
```

The `:play` part is optional and makes spotify automatically start playing when it's loaded

The play list id `37i9dQZF1DXaTIN6XNquoW` is Michael Jackson. Replace it with another, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

First open the Spotify SDK. If it possible you could do it, if not it means impossible. Because only developer of app could register intents inside the AndroidManifest.